# Как получить самый первый ImageView с RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, view

Хочу сделать подсказку (TapTarget) на первой картинке в RecyclerView. Как к ней обратиться из кода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё что нужно на месте:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
private ArrayList<Task> data;
private SectionDetailAdapter adapter;
```

Код весь не привожу, так как с кодом проблем нет. Нужна помощь с идеей.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите что-то сделать с 1-ой `View` сделайте это внутри `ViewHolder-а.` Что вам мешает в методе `onBindViewHolder()` сделать проверку на 1ый элемент и задать ей нужные свойства?

Если вы хотите каким-то образом вытащить вашу `View` наружу, то вы можете в том же `onBindViewHolder()` написать небольшой костыль вроде такого:

```
if(position == 0) {
    firstView = holder.itemView;
}
```

Ну и потом дергать эту самую `View` через какой-нибудь геттер. Это корневая `View` разметки вашего элемента, вы можете оттуда ваш `ImageView` вытащить с помощью метода `findViewById()` Но я бы так делать точно не стал.

Если же вам нужно обработать особенный клик (из вашего описания не очень понятно, что именно вам нужно), то вы можете создать свой [кастомный  ClickListener](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) который вы прокините в `Activity` и в качестве аргументов туда положите саму `View` и позицию `ViewHolder-а`.